# Debug assertion failed when trying to delete array from heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a sub-optimal solution to return two variables from a function by creating a pointer to an array with two indexes. (just using my current knowledge base from class. I know vectors or `std::pair` would be a better solution)

However, when I try to delete the array via the pointer, I'm getting the below error.

Am I misunderstanding the procedure? Is this array not created in heap and therefore no need for explicit deletion?

### Edit: Quick Comment

thanks to those that are providing more ideal formulations for the type of problem I'm trying to solve. I am (was) just trying to understand the specific behavior of this error I was getting.

I realize this is not an optimal way to store two variables. Just code to experiment with some features of C++. Feel free to provide better formulations for the general benefit of others.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double* quadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
    double x1, x2;

    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    double arr[2] = {x1, x2};
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    double* solution = quadraticEquation(3, 5, -8);

    double x1 = solution[0];
    double x2 = solution[1];
    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << std::endl << "x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;

    delete[] solution;
    solution = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a stack allocated variable. You can't use delete[] on that.

Comment: should I still move the solution pointer the `nullptr`? I'm having trouble identifying when a pointer is to the stack and to the heap. Is heap only with the keywork `new`?

Comment: Stop messing around with C-style arrays and use `std::array` instead.  Then you can return it by value.  In this particular example, `std::pair` would also do the job.

Comment: @PaulSanders I know this is hard for some people on StackOverflow to understand... but some of us in school have to use the the data types professors ask of us. As I indicated in the question, I'm aware there are "better" solutions, but we're not always allowed to use them.

Comment: @Hofbr *I know this is hard for some people on StackOverflow to understand.* -- No, what you should understand is that unless you specify *exactly* what you cannot use, then we assume that you can use whatever is available in C++.  We have no idea if you are a student with some sort of restriction placed on you as to what to use, or a new, independent C++ programmer who is not aware of `std::array`, and are happy that they are learning about something new to use.

Comment: @Hofbr Yes you're correct, if you use `new` then it's going on the heap (I am ignoring lots of stuff like make_shared/make_unique/placement new/...etc because I assume this is your first time with C++). Since this is C++ I assume you will not use `malloc` and friends. For example, when you wrote `double arr[2] = {x1, x2};`, there was no `new` anywhere, so it's going on the stack.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm very excited to learn new things. Though I did state in my question I was aware that things like `std::pair` are better solutions and (by implication) I'm aware of them. Which is why I'm asking the specific question about precisely what behavior I'm experiencing as is... not what would be a better formulation. However, I could have been more explicit in my question that I'm not needing better formulations just seeking to understand (ultimately) why deleting this pointer is wrong.

Comment: _some of us in school have to use the data types professors ask of us_ OK, fair enough, so what are they please?  You should add this information to your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should return heap allocated memory. You could use `new double[2]` or a smart pointer.

```cpp
double* quadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
  double x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  double x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  return new double[2]{x1, x2};
}
```

With smart pointers you don't need to remember to deallocate the heap memory, the usage looks like this.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<double[]> quadraticEquationSmartPointer(double a, double b, double c) {
  double x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  double x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  return std::unique_ptr<double[]>(new double[2]{x1, x2});
}

int main() {
  auto solution = quadraticEquationSmartPointer(3, 5, -8);
  double x1 = solution[0];
  double x2 = solution[1];
  std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << std::endl << "x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;
}
```

But in this case it would be easier to just return a `std::pair<double, double>` or a `std::tuple<double, double>`, also more secure, as it gives you the number of values you should expect.

With pair is even easier.

```cpp
std::pair<double, double> quadraticEquationPair(double a, double b, double c) {
  double x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  double x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
  return std::make_pair(x1, x2);
}

int main() {
  auto [x1, x2] = quadraticEquationPair(3, 5, -8);
  std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << std::endl << "x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd change the code to use `std::pair<double, double>` since, as you said in your answer, it's a far better solution.

Comment: `return std::make_pair(x1, x2);` -- You could shorthen this to: `return {x1, x2};`